# Select date from my db without seconds using PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Well,
I save the date's with minutes and second in my database.

And I want to check if the date from `my db = to date today`.

I read about this, and I don't know how to use in `Date_format`
Maybe because my `Date` is varchar(255)..

Thanks for helps (:

EDIT:

**Thanks all (:**

Answer (score 0):

You just need simple conversion when you are having ur date in `varchar`. Your query should be like:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2015-08-21 12:35:15', '%Y-%M-%d %H:%i');
```

OUTPUT

```
2015-August-21 12:35
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$dbdate = '8/21/2015 11:16:12 AM'; //add your database date here
$dt = new DateTime($dbdate);
$date = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
$today = date("Y-m-d"); //get current date


//now compare your dates
if($date == $today)
{
}
```

Comment: @UnderPhp A quick suggestion. If you find an answer that works for you, make sure to mark that answer as "accepted". Makes the management of the site and sorting of the questions a lot easier! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a date in date format like timestamp for an efficient search.

With this format you can make some search like :

```
SELECT id, date FROM data WHERE date BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("2015-08-20 23:04:00") AND TIMESTAMP("2015-08-21 12:04:00")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(t.datestring, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Hey, i tried it.. Its work in SQL in my PMA(PhpMyAdmin), But the result in php is output: 00/00/0000..

My code is as answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32134874/5080564

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%Y/%m/%d') FROM `sometable`

Comment: Thanks for comment, see my code please http://stackoverflow.com/a/32134874/5080564

Answer (score 0):

Its not answer, I have a small problem..

I tried it:

```
$dbdate = "21/08/2015 10:13";
```

.

```
   $select_last_vote = mysql_query("SELECT `Date` FROM `Vote` WHERE `IP` = '$ip' AND `VoteID` = '$VoteID' order by `Date` DESC LIMIT 1;");
            $select_last_vote = mysql_fetch_array($select_last_vote);
            $dbdate = $select_last_vote["Date"];
            $takeResult = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('$dbdate', '%d/%m/%Y' ), '%d/%m/%Y') as Date ;");
            $Result_date = mysql_fetch_array($takeResult);
            $result_date = $Result_date["Date"];
            $today = date("d/m/Y");
    if($result_date == $today)
        {
        echo "this is today $result_date, $today";
        }
        else { // there is my output: You can vote! 00/00/0000
        echo "You can vote! $result_date";
        }
```

Its working now (:

Thanks for all!!