# Count rows by date_format PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to count the number of votes of this day but without the minutes and seconds. My intention is to count the votes of the table today Voteslist and VoteID($_GET) equal to "2" for example.

1. I saved the date's with hours and minuts.
2. I select the date without the second (by date_format) for do check's.
3. The date before the "date_format" can be: 00/00/000 ti:me AND after: 00/00/000
4. I have problem in this var `$today_voting_query`.

   ```
   $select_information = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Vote` WHERE `VoteID` = '$VoteID';");
           $take = mysql_fetch_array($select_information);
           $createdBy = $take["Username"];
           $select_last_vote = mysql_query("SELECT `Date` FROM `voteslist` WHERE `IP` = '$ip' AND `VoteID` = '$VoteID' order by `Date` DESC LIMIT 1;");
           $select_last_vote = mysql_fetch_array($select_last_vote);
           $dbdate = $select_last_vote["Date"];
           $takeResult = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('$dbdate', '%d/%m/%Y' ), '%d/%m/%Y') as Date ;");
           $Result_date = mysql_fetch_array($takeResult);
           $result_date = $Result_date["Date"];
           $today = date("d/m/Y");
           $thanks_to = $createdBy;

           // HERE IS MY PROBLEM
           $today_voting_query = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('$dbdate', '%d/%m/%Y' ), '%d/%m/%Y') as Date, COUNT(ID) AS countID FROM `voteslist` WHERE `VoteID` = '$VoteID' AND `Date` = '$result_date';");
           $today_voting = mysql_fetch_array($today_voting_query);
           $today_voting = $today_voting[1]; //OUTPUT: 0 , and I have 2 rows..
           $total_voting_q = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `Vote` WHERE `VoteID` = '$VoteID';");
           $total_voting_f = mysql_fetch_array($total_voting_q);
           $total_voting = $total_voting_f[0];
           if($today_voting == 0)
           {
               $today_voting = "No new votes today";
           }

           if(strlen($InstaCredit) > 3)
           {
               $thanks_to = "<a class='thanks-to'>$thanks_to</a>";
           }

           //now compare your dates
           if($result_date == $today)
           {
               echo "<span class='thanks-for-voting voted'>
               You can't vote again to <strong>{$thanks_to}</strong>
               </span><br />
               <span class='note-vote voted'>You can vote only one time in 24hours</span>";
           }
           else {
           $new_vote = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `voteslist` (`ID`, `Username`, `IP`, `VoteID`, `Date`) VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION['username']."', '$ip', '$VoteID', '$date');");
               echo "
               <span class='thanks-for-voting'>
               Thanks about vote to<strong>{$thanks_to}</strong>!
               </span>
               ";
           }
   ?>
       <div class="statics">
       <span id="static-title">Static of <?php echo $thanks_to; ?></span>
       <span id="static-q">Today votes:</span><span id="static-a"><?php echo $today_voting; ?></span><br />
       <span id="static-q">Total votes:</span><span id="static-a"><?php echo $total_voting; ?></span><br />
       </div>
   ```

   Maybe is help you to understand me:

   [How to count rows by date using MySQL and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138523/how-to-count-rows-by-date-using-mysql-and-php)

   [Select date from my db without seconds using PHP MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32134104/5080564)

**It's hard to explain, but if you dont understand something left comment..**

Please try to help me, It's important for me..

Thanks for helpers

Comment: you know, most of your date mangling could be avoided if you just stored your dates as actual dates, instead of varchars? then you  could use mysql's NATIVE date/time functions and handling instead of having to convert everything from varchar->mysql date and then further mangle in PHP. And roundtripping a php date string through mysql just to reformat it? That's totally cargo-cult programming.

Comment: It would probably be easier to write a program to convert them all to actual date than query than what you want to accomplish